# Web page accent issue

Tags: javascript, html, diacritics

On my web page, a word inside a button didn't accept an accent, so far coded as charset = iso-8859-1, but when I changed it to charset = utf-8, my other button (inside bootstrap formatting) was with the error. Any idea what it is? I have already tried to change my codepage to 1252, currently it is 65001.

Comment: What encoding are the actual files using?  Are they written in UTF8 or something else?

Comment: That's the point, i'm working in a someone work, so, I don't know... I don't know PHP, so I can't use the mb_detect_encoding function...